# How to dynamically add index on the server side in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Lets say I'm making an app with firebase where the user can create permanent lobbies in which they can send permanent dated messages to. The lobby's name is a key in my data structure. What I want to do is that each time a new lobby is created, an index is automatically created on the server side to sort the messages of that lobby by date.

That can probably be done if I have another server listening in to the creation of new lobbies but is there a way to do this without having an additional server? Just through the client? Without compromising the security of the app?

(Note: I'm using the Unity sdk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically add an index, short from updating a `rules.json` file and uploading it with the Firebase tools/CLI, which I'd highly recommend against.

If you find you need to dynamically add indexes, you've probably structured your data wrong. But without seeing a minimal sample of the JSON (as text, no screenshots please) that reproduces the problem, it is impossible to say more than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Push()` function on a database reference. This will create a unique key based on the timestamp so all values can easily be sorted chronologically.

Use `Push()` anytime you need to generate a new unique key on your database. You can use this for the lobby itself and even the conversations within the lobby.

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#append_to_a_list_of_data)